# How to map additional column of many-to-many join table to the association map key?

Tags: java, hibernate

There is an entity call **Version** and this entity has an inner join many-to-many relationship. The bridge table **VER_EQUIVALENTS** has columns [VER_ID, EQUIVALENT_VER_ID, CODE] and the CODE column contains the code of the equivalent version.

This is how I implemented this relationship.

```java
public class Version {
        
   private String code;
         
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(
      name = "VER_EQUIVALENTS",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "VER_ID")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EQUIVALENT_VER_ID")}
   )
   @MapKey(name = "code")
   @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
   private Map<String, Version> equivalentVersions = new HashMap<String, Version>();
        
}
```

This is what I got when I try to insert a version contains equivalent versions.

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("VER_EQUIVALENTS"."CODE")
```

What can I do to set the **CODE** value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand that you need, you should correct your mapping in the following way:

```java
public class Version {
    
   // ...
   
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(
      name = "VER_EQUIVALENTS",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "VER_ID")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EQUIVALENT_VER_ID")}
   )
   @MapKeyColumn(name = "CODE")
   private Map<String, Version> equivalentVersions = new HashMap<String, Version>();
    
}
```